# Como Validar Input Do Usuário dentro de um arquivo .txt

Tags: python

Tenho um programa de cadastro que recebe o dados do usuário (e-mail e senha), esse dados vão para um arquivo .txt, com a função **Open()** do python, exemplo:

**Arquivo txt**

```
exemplo@gmail.com, senha1234
outroexeplo@gmail.com, 12345678
```

Primeiro é escrito o e-mail do usuário depois vem uma "," para separar o e-mail da senha.

Após o usuário se cadastrar ele precisa fazer o login. Ai que está o problema, **como que eu posso fazer para verificar dentro do arquivo `.txt` se a senha que o usuário digitou no login corresponde com o email dele?**

**Código**

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
```

**def LogIn():**

```
sg.theme('Black')
layout = [
    [sg.Text('E-mail'), sg.Input(size=(25,5), key='email')],
    [sg.Text('Senha'), sg.Input(size=(25,0), key='Pass')],
    [sg.Button('Log-in')]
]

#  Gerar Janela
janela = sg.Window('Log-in', layout)
button, values = janela.Read()

#  Armazenando valores
email = values['email']
Pass = values['Pass']


#  Condicionais
if '@gmail.com' not in email[-10:]:
    pass


elif len(Pass) < 8:
    print('Senha deve conter 8 ou mais caracteres')


else:

    with open(r'Works\Log-in\obb\bcdds.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        dados = file.read()

        if email not in dados:
            print('E-mail não cadastrado.')

        elif Pass:
            **Aqui vem a checagem para saber se a senha corresponde ao email**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça uma recursão em cada registro do arquivo e compare o email assim que encontrar o email correspondente compare a senha digita e se for verdadeiro
faça algo.

Exemplo pseudo codigo:

```
    for line in dado:
         eml,password = line.split(",")

         if eml == email and senha == password:
           #Do Stufff
```